# No Export option in Xcode 10 for Development/Adhoc/Enterprise

Tags: ios, xcode10

In Xcode 10 there seems the export option is not available for Development / Adhoc / Enterprise mode.

[image]

But for when we go through "Distribute app" and choose "iOS App Store" then it show "Export" option there.

And if I choose to proceed with any other option other than "iOS App Store" then I end up in the following screen.
[image]
next
[image]

- But whats the use on exporting an app using Distribution certificate since we can't install the app using distribution certificate unless we upload via TestFlight.

So how to export a build with Adhoc / Development mode ?

Comment: you must choose Ad Hoc option not iOS App Store for Adhoc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After clicking on "Distribute App" you should see the following window:

[image]

You simply need to select the required distribution method; App Store, Ad-Hoc, Enterprise or Development.

After you select "Development" and click Next you should be prompted to select additional options:

[image]

You will then select your signing options and click Next

[image]

Finally you will get an option to export your app.

[image]

Since you have selected the option to create a manifest file for over the air distribution, you need to supply the requested URLs at step 2 before you can proceed. (Alternatively, deselect that option).

Comment: Yes, I can see those options as I also mentioned the same in my questions, But there is no export option for any of those options except for "iOS App Store" thats the problem. Because we follow an approach for testing where we need to keep the IPA file of "Development" in our local server use it, but as of now I can't able to export that IPA file like I could do in Xcode 9 and previous versions.

Comment: Select "Development", click Next.  Chose your additional options, Click Next. Chose your signing options, click Next. Click Export.

Comment: Ya, I performed but it ends up with the screens which I have added in question now, could you please check it and help out.

Comment: Hi, its working now, the issue is I have chosen "Include manifest for over the air installation" option, If I choose it the export options is not appearing, Once I unselect it and proceed further export option is available. Thank you. Can you please update this content with the answer so I can mark the answer as right one.

Comment: If you select the option to include the manifest then you cannot proceed until you have supplied the requested URLs

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on distribution you will see that option. Check this image:

[image]

Now if you go ahead with **Adhoc** or **Development** option in the end you will land on this page which will allow you to export the beta for development or adhoc usage.

[image]

Comment: As you said if I go ahead with Adhoc or Development I end up with other screen rather than the screen you showed above, I have added those screenshots with the question now, can you please check those images now and guide me further ? Also one more question may I know which version of Xcode you are using ? Xcode 10 or new Xcode 10 beta version ?